# How can I draw a specific 2D maze?

Tags: windows, images, drawing

I have a map of a 2D maze that I sketched on paper from a real maze, and I want to recreate the maze on my computer in a nice and neat "white passable blocks with impassible black wall between blocks" picture format so that I can present it to others.

However, when I try to search for a method for doing such job, I'm flooded with results for 2D maze *generation*, instead of 2D maze sketching.

How can I sketch an arbitrary 2D maze in a convenient way? I know I can do it with Microsoft Word with huge tables with same width/height, but it's tedious to manipulate the edges.

Comment: For the MS Word solution: did you try the "Draw table" option? This gives you a "pen" on the screen that makes it relatively easy to manipulate the borders of the table. An alternative could be to draw it on a paper and scan your maze and optionally edit/enhance it in image manipulation software, such as GIMP or Photoshop. Also: could you give an indication how big the grid size of your maze is?

Comment: Or maybe try it in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Word Table,
create a grid of columns and rows "boxes "
use the "Fill" function to create your maze.